# PHPOffice/Word - Error when generate multiple files from template

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive, phpoffice

I'm using the PHPOffice/Word package to generate word files from template and i use Laravel 5.8 version running on PHP Server 7.3.29.

The generation works pretty good when i download only one word document, but when i want to generate multiple word files in a `foreach` loop, i got that error : `ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object`.

Here is the code (the error is on the line with the `saveAs` method) :

```php
      $template_path = $request->FILE_PATH;
      try {
        $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($template_path);
      }
      catch(\Exception $e) {
        return back()->with('danger',"Erreur lors de l'export - Vérifier le nom et le chemin de la maquette");
      }
      foreach(explode(",",$request->IDS_CONTACT) as $idContact) {
        $contact = Contact::find($idContact);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('date_jour',$request->DT_ENVOI_PACK);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('IDENTITE','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('ADRESSE','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('projet','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('ADRESSE_BIS','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('CODE_POSTAL','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('VILLE','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('form_politesse','Test');
        $templateProcessor->setValue('object_pack',$request->OBJ_PACK);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('form_politesse2','Test');
        $filename = time() . "PackBienvenue.docx";
        $templateProcessor->saveAs(storage_path('exports\\'.$filename));
        sleep(1);
      }
```

What is surprising is that it still works fine on the first generation and i got my word document before it raise the Exception that i have put before. But it stop there and the following generations do not work.

I thought first that was a problem with the filename which was overwrite, so i have put the `time` method to be sure that each document have different filename.

And also, i have an old version of Word (Word 2010 version 14), don't think that this is the problem but in doubt i prefer to precise it...

If someone have ever done something like this before, i would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who would be interested, i fix the issue by (re)creating at each loop tour a `TemplateProcessor` object.
Not sure that this is the best way to fix this error, but it works !

Full code like this :

```php
// code 
      foreach(explode(",",$request->IDS_CONTACT) as $idContact) {
        try {
          $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($template_path);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
          return back()->with('danger',"Erreur lors de l'export - Vérifier le nom et le chemin de la maquette");
        }
        $contact = Contact::find($idContact);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('date_jour',$request->DT_ENVOI_PACK);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('IDENTITE',$contact->identite);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('ADRESSE',$contact->ADRESSE1);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('projet',$projet->LIBELLE_PROJ);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('ADRESSE_BIS',$contact->ADRESSE2);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('CODE_POSTAL',$contact->CDPOST);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('VILLE',$contact->COMMUNE);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('form_politesse',$contact->getFormulePolitesse());
        $templateProcessor->setValue('object_pack',$request->OBJ_PACK);
        $templateProcessor->setValue('form_politesse2',strtolower($contact->getFormulePolitesse()));
        $filename = time() . "PackBienvenue.docx";
        $templateProcessor->saveAs(storage_path('exports\\'.$filename));
      }
```